# Snappy - Wrong conversion from pixel to lat long

Tags: python, coordinates, latitude-longitude, snappy

I'm using snappy to try to find out what are the x,y coordinates in order to crop an image.

I've done a few tests using snappy functions but i've noticed that there is something wrong with them. I've converted a X,Y from the image to latitude and longitude and then,using those coordinates, I tried to convert them again into X,Y but i didn't get the same result.

The idea or final purpose is to get the LatLong coordinates from a geojson, read them, and using those coordinates get the X,Y in the image.

Notice that the path refers to a tiff file.

```
from snappy import ProductIO
from snappy import PixelPos, GeoPos
import numpy as np

path='/home/.../x.tiff'
###############################################################################
product = ProductIO.readProduct(path)
sg = product.getSceneGeoCoding()

def LatLon_from_XY(ProductSceneGeoCoding, x, y):
    #From x,y position in satellite image (SAR), get the Latitude and Longitude
    geopos = ProductSceneGeoCoding.getGeoPos(PixelPos(x, y), None)
    latitude = geopos.getLat()
    longitude = geopos.getLon()
    return latitude, longitude

latitude, longitude = LatLon_from_XY(sg, 11048, 1365)

print('LatLong from PixelPosition')
print(latitude)
print(longitude)
### 38.3976151718
### -5.47978868123

###############################################################################

def getPixelPosFromLatLong(source, lat,lon):
    if sg.canGetPixelPos() is not True:
        raise Exception('Cant''t get Pixel Position from this source')
    else:
        pos = GeoPos(lat,lon)
        pixpos = sg.getPixelPos(pos,None)
        X = np.round(pixpos.getX())
        Y = np.round(pixpos.getY())
    return [X,Y]

[X,Y] = getPixelPosFromLatLong(path, 38.3976151718, -5.47978868123)

print('Pixel Position from LatLong')
print(X)
print(Y)
### 10715.0
### 1143.0
```

Is there any other way to get the X,Y pixel from an image using lat long?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are wondering about the same problem I find out this solution:

Change the path to refers not to a .tiff file but the folder .SAFE

Then, I write again my functions and now it looks like this:

```
from snappy import ProductIO
from snappy import PixelPos, GeoPos
import numpy as np

def LatLon_from_XY(ProductSceneGeoCoding, x, y):
    geoPos = ProductSceneGeoCoding.getGeoPos(PixelPos(x,y),None)
    lat = geoPos.getLat()
    lon = geoPos.getLon()
    return lat,lon

def XY_from_LatLon(ProductSceneGeoCoding, latitude, longitude):
    pixelPos = ProductSceneGeoCoding.getPixelPos(GeoPos(latitude, longitude),None)
    x = np.round(pixelPos.getX())
    y = np.round(pixelPos.getY())
    return x,y

###############################################################################

#Notice that the path does not refer to any file but to the folder .SAFE
path = '/.../X.SAFE'
product = ProductIO.readProduct(path)
sg = product.getSceneGeoCoding()
originalX = 13000
originalY = 13000

print('Original X,Y: ', originalX,originalY)

lat,lon = LatLon_from_XY(sg, originalX, originalY)
print(lat,lon)

x,y = XY_from_LatLon(sg,lat,lon)
print(x,y)

originalLat = 37.36475504265766
originalLon = -5.972416873450527

print('Original Lat,Lon: ', originalLat, originalLon)

x,y = XY_from_LatLon(sg, originalLat, originalLon)
print(x,y)

lat,lon = LatLon_from_XY(sg, x, y)
print(lat,lon)
```

This way, I get almost the same values (13000 ~ 13006)